# Watch and wc not yielding any results

Tags: bash, zsh, watch, wc

I try to constantly display the size of the current folder using watch , the below command does not work however, what do I do wrong ? I use `zsh` shell 
`$ watch ls -a | wc -l`

Comment: I guess what you really want is `watch 'ls -a | wc -l'` (notice the quotes).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works, but for other options however, for example  when I try `watch du -sh <directory>` I do not need the quotes, do you know why this is? Thanks

Comment: Without quotes, `watch` will watch the result of `ls -a` and whatever that produces will be forwarded by the shell to `wc -l`. With quotes, `watch` will watch the result of `ls -a | wc -l`

Answer (score 2):

> what do I do wrong ?

Shell parses `|` as a pipe. So when shell sees:

```
watch ls -a | wc -l
```

It parses it as two command with one command output redirected to the other:

```
( watch ls -a )      |          ( wc -l )
```

It runs the command `watch` with two arguments `ls` and `-a` and a command `wc` with single argument `-l`. Because `watch ls -a` never ends and `wc -l` only outputs when the input ends, you don't see anything printed out. `wc -l` waits until all input lines are printed, which never happens.

Because `watch` internally calls the shell, you can:

```
watch 'ls -a | wc -l'
```

This runs a single command `watch` with one argument `ls -a | wc -l`. `watch` internally spawns a shell and passes the string `ls -a | wc -l` to it. Then this internal shell spawns two new processes `ls -a` and `wc -l` with input/output connected.